# Using same SSL certificate for Apache and socketio web server for same application

Tags: python, apache, ssl, gevent-socketio

I am writing an in house application where my main web server is Apache web server hosting the main web portal which is being accessed by HTTPS. The certificates are self signed certificate and sites will not be accessed over internet but VPN may be.

On one of the webpage in my application I am establishing the separate connection to the socketio based server using HTTPS again but on different port. Hostnames are same for main URL and socketio's URL.

If I use two different SSL certificates for both URLs, all goes fine. However, if I try to use the same SSL certificate , application is unable to connect to socket io server.

I want to use the same certificate for both the URLs (same host , different ports). Isn't it possible?

I recieve below Error at the backend through gevent socketio.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nobackup/kdhotre/Intracer/16.0.293/C-Int/3rdparty/python2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent-1.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/nobackup/kdhotre/Intracer/16.0.293/C-Int/3rdparty/python2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent-1.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/server.py", line 102, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
  File "/nobackup/kdhotre/Intracer/16.0.293/C-Int/3rdparty/python2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent-1.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/ssl.py", line 383, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/nobackup/kdhotre/Intracer/16.0.293/C-Int/3rdparty/python2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent-1.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/ssl.py", line 87, in __init__
    cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs)
SSLError: [Errno 336445442] _ssl.c:351: error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
<Greenlet at 0x1b363050: <bound method SocketIOServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of

<SocketIOServer at 0x1b25bc90 fileno=10 address=72.163.134.156:5501>>

(<socket at 0x1b35de50 fileno=11 sock=72.163.134.15, ('10.142.149.112', 64062))> failed with SSLError
```